# Immediately reloading table view (Parse + Swift)

Tags: swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I'm able to retrieve a user's photo and 2 text fields from Parse and populate it in a new table cell.. However, the next added cell only shows when the app is restarted. How can I have it so the next cell is displayed immediately after a user saves to Parse?

Thanks!

Comment: Please show some code for the part where you are saving the user. Also, is `myTableView` of type `UITableView` or Parse's `PFQueryTableView`?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to reload the data from parse (using what I assume is your original fetch) then you will have to reload to the table, like so:

```
myTableView.reloadData()
```

An alternative, depending a lot upon your specific app, may be to update your local interface separately while you the save the data back to parse.

Comment: What do you mean reload from parse? I'm already using myTableView.reloadData() and the table view reloads. But it doesn't reload immediately..it only reloads when the app restarts or the next cell has been created.

Comment: are you fetching the update results from parse again? Please update your question with your code

Comment: Updated. The two methods you see retrieve the info...is there something i need to be doing on the parse background?

Comment: Ok, are you running these functions again after you save the data?

Comment: Yes, in viewDidLoad(). And everything works great...just the next cell only displays after a new cell has been created and so forth.